# what is the difference between `createActivity` and `shadowOf`?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I saw this roboletirc example:

```
 @Test
  public void shouldHaveHappySmiles() throws Exception {
    String hello = new MainActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
    assertThat(hello, equalTo("Hello world!"));
  }

  @Before
  public void setup()  {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class)
        .create().get();
  }
  @Test
  public void checkActivityNotNull() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(activity);
  }

  @Test
  public void buttonClickShouldStartNewActivity() throws Exception 
  {
      Button button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button2);
      button.performClick();
          Intent intent = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity).peekNextStartedActivity();
          assertEquals(SecondActivity.class.getCanonicalName(), inten

t.getComponent().getClassName());
  }
```

I tried to look in documentation but didn't understand the difference between `createActivity` and `shadowOf`. can someone please shed some light?

btw, why is there a `new MainActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);` in this test? when should I use `new` instead of `createActivity()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Shadows provide substitute functionality for the actual class when testing. They also sometimes provide functionality not found in the class they shadow so that you can turn features on and off and check check on internal values of the object being shadowed.

For example: Turning off google analytics in test classes

ShadowApplication shadowApplication =
   Robolectric.shadowOf_(Robolectric.application);
  shadowApplication.declareActionUnbindable("com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START");

About Shadows: 
http://robolectric.org/extending/

Don't use "New" use buildActivity. This gives you complete control of the Activity lifecycle so that you can check things on the Activity after each step in the startup cycle. You can call get() without calling onResume for example.

```
activitySome = 
Robolectric.buildActivity(SomeActivity.class).withIntent(intent).create().start().resume().visible().get();
```

You can call getResources() on the activity class after calling .get() on buildActivity.